# What's wrong with this code? It's doing nothing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<HTML>
  <HEAD>
    <script> 
        $(function(){

            $(window).on('hashchange', function() {
                var hash = location.hash.replace( /^#/, '' );
                document.title = 'example ' + hash;
            });


            $(window).trigger('hashchange');
        });
    </script> 
    <TITLE>example</TITLE>
  </HEAD>
  <BODY>
  </body>
</HTML>
```

Let's say the `<title>` of example.com is example

This code should automatically update the page title for `example.com/#city1` to `example city1` and `example.com/#city2` to `example city2` and so on.

I have only an index.html file and I don't want to add php file to my html file.

Comment: Probably you're executing the javascript before the title tag is loaded.

Comment: You haven't included jQuery.

Comment: Your code is working, have you added the jquery script?

Comment: Haven’t you [asked this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48792633) already about two hours ago? Didn’t the comments already point you towards the obvious solution?

Comment: In the future, use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the comments you need to add the jQuery library to your page using :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js">
```

Then your code should work as expected.